# Shared Preferences Adding MultipleValues

Tags: android

I`m trying to pass 3 int values to another class using shared preferences. But the issue is that only first value gets added the remaining two values only default values are shown.

The shared prefs editor is committed;
The main function is fragment activity,the second one is fragment
This getsharedprefs is used to access the shared preferences from fragment

here is my code

```
 {
   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
   SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPrefsEditor;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_help_images);
    sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("values",MODE_PRIVATE);
    sharedPrefsEditor=sharedPreferences.edit();
    sharedPrefsEditor.putInt("length",length);
    sharedPrefsEditor.putInt("response1",intentResponse1);
    sharedPrefsEditor.putInt("response2",intentResponse2);

    sharedPrefsEditor.commit();
```

}

this is my second class
{

```
    sharedPreferences=this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("values", 
                                                 Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    length=sharedPreferences.getInt("length",-1);
    intentResponse1=sharedPreferences.getInt("response1",0);
    intentResponse1=sharedPreferences.getInt("response2",-1);
```

}

all the variables are declared properly,
this is my first question in stack overflow, so kindly bear any mistakes i made

Comment: Better You can use Parcelable , bundle or normal putExtras to send the data to next class/fragment.

Comment: but i dont want to start the second activity from first one just the value need to be passed @android_dev

Comment: post what have you tried ?

Comment: myFragment.setArguments(args); use this function to pass arguments from Activity to Fragment.